# Android-Google Map add polygon on Ui thread

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a number of polygons on google map. While I am adding polygons to the map it hangs up UI thread. Is there any way that I can process this on another thread?

Edit:

1. I am calculating coordinates in Asyntask,adding the PolygonOptions object to arraylist.
2. In onPostExecute, I am adding polygons like this:

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<polygonOptionsArrayList.size();i++)
   {
   map.addPolygon(polygonOptionsArrayList.get(i));
   }
   ```

   This is where the UI hangs.

Comment: show some code how you are doing this

Comment: You can compute your polygon related data on a separate thread, but map drawing must be done on UI thread. How many polygons are you managing?

Comment: you are getting coordinates from where ? ... a remote host or an api ??? post some code ...

Comment: As Antonio said, Map Drawing must be done on UI thread but that makes UI thread unresponsive. Is there any work around?

Comment: As a workaround you can add to the map only the polygons that are visible based on the map's visible region, changing these polygons everytime the camera changes

Comment: If user zooms outs , I have to load all the polygons. Not to mention, the overhead of tracking visibility region, matching those coordinates to find out which polygon should be drawn from the arraylist. That won't work. Anyway, thanks @antonio

Comment: Of course if the user zooms out you won't want to show all the polygons. You could for example cluster the polygons. As I don't know how many polygons you are managing, where you are getting them from or how complex (number of points) they have, I can't provide a better workaround/solution

Comment: @karanvs Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Marty.H I had to reduce the number of points I used to render the polygon. I could not find a solution to render in separate thread than UI. If you find one , please let me know too.

Comment: @karanvs I basically used a loading screen / progress bar in combination with runnables/handlers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875583/prevent-crashing-while-heavy-process/46896120#46896120