# Prevent crashing while heavy process

Tags: java, android

I am making a Map based app where users would often load over 10k polygons on the map.  The only problem is that the only way to add a polygon to the map is in the UI thread, which means when I add them it will either freeze for 5 - 10 seconds or it will crash.

I'm ready to accept that it will just have to take time to load, but is there a way I can slow down the for loop when the system is struggling to prevent the crashing and even the freezing?  One method I have thought of is putting a short delay on the for loop, but that will be less than ideal as it will have to take much longer then it has to to be on the safe side.

```
          protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, ArrayList> result){
            for(String key : result.keySet()){
                List<PolygonOptions> thisList = result.get(key);
                for(PolygonOptions poly: thisList){
                    Polygon thisPoly = mMap.addPolygon(poly);
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I would think that the problem is trying to load "over 10k polygons on the map". The user cannot perceive 10K polygons on a map at once. This is akin to trying to put 10K markers on a map at once, and for that, we use marker clustering, both to reduce information overload and to improve performance.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have implemented methods to set them as hidden when off screen, but adding them and removing them from the map would be much harder as they could stack and it seems to be more work for the system to add/remove rather than show/hide.

Comment: I face a similar problem and I solve it elegantly showing a message on a non responsive transparent layer to the user on the screen while, after returning to the main thread from the task, a loop iterates doing tasks for pieces of the big job. The user can see a message and even progress and the UI is not locked.

Comment: @WalterPalladino I like your solution.  I am doing exactly that. However, I am having trouble with the loop doing pieces of the big job - it is still freezing the UI.  Can you write an answer so I can see how you did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is a pseudo code about how I solve this:

```
private final Handler handler_render_data = new Handler ();
private int actualItemRendering;
private static final int HANDLER_RUN_DELAY = 1000;



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //  Display the message telling the user to wait
    //  This Linear Layout includes a text and cover all teh screen
    lyt_report_progress = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.lyt_report_progress);
    lyt_report_progress.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    lyt_report_progress.requestFocus ();
    lyt_report_progress.setClickable (true);

    //  Your code calling your async task

}

//  Your callback from your async task
private void callbackHere (Data myData) {

    this.localMyData = myData;

    //  You store your data locally and start the rendering process
    actualItemRendering = 0;
    handler_render_data.post (createDataFromTaskResult);
}


private Runnable createDataFromTaskResult = new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run () {

        if (actualItemRendering < myData.length ()) {

            //  Render your data here

            //  Continue with the next item to render
            actualItemRendering++;
            handler_render_data.post (createDataFromTaskResult);

        } else {
            //  All fields were rendered
            handler.postDelayed (hideProgressBarTask, HANDLER_RUN_DELAY);
        }
    }
};

private Runnable hideProgressBarTask = new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run () {

        lyt_report_progress.setVisibility (View.GONE);

    }
};
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that out!  I still have a little freezing, but it is much better and I should be able to tinker around with the list sizes to get that right.  The main thing is that they are firing one after the other instead of all at once.

Comment: You could fire several at once but will require more resources because more than one thread will be executed concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into several tasks and execute each task on main thread separately. I.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { .. process 1/20 of your work });
}
```

You don't need to add a delay. Also you can experiment with granularity, probably better to increase it from 1/20.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after. Thanks.